# Reactjs and Typescript - Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This type checking problem took me all day and I still have not solved it. I searched everywhere, but I see that no one has gone through it. Could someone give me a light? thank you!

```
 <input
        type="text"
        value={shareURLValue}
        className={classnames("share-url-holder", {
            shared: Boolean(shareId) && !shareHidden,
        })}
        ref={saveShareURLRef}
        onClick={e => {
            e.target.select(); #Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
        }}
        onKeyUp={e => {
            e.target.select(); #Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
        }}
    />
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`.

From the react type definitions:

```
interface SyntheticEvent<T> {
    // other properties...

    /**
     * A reference to the element on which the event listener is registered.
     */
    currentTarget: EventTarget & T;

    // If you thought this should be `EventTarget & T`, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/12239
    /**
     * A reference to the element from which the event was originally dispatched.
     * This might be a child element to the element on which the event listener is registered.
     *
     * @see currentTarget
     */
    target: EventTarget;
}
```

In other words, `target` might not be the `input` element when it's a MouseEvent. Use `currentTarget` to get the element that the event handler is bound to.

Comment: It seems you right, I'll solve other issues (that showed up), do tests and come back to to you it worked out, I was afraid to do this (I had seen other examples as yours) because using "select" seems to me necessary. We'll see. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I got this working:

```
const handleSomeEvent = (e: SyntheticEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  /* now you have type-safe access to all the things */
  e.currentTarget.[stuff]
}

return <input onClick={handleSomeEvent} onKeyUp={handleSomeEvent} {...otherProps}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to be more explicit about the type of your event args:

```
onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HtmlInputElement>)  => {
            e.target.select(); #Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
        }}
```

and

```
onKeyUp={(e: React.KeyBoardEvent<HtmlInputElement>) => {
            e.target.select(); #Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
        }}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help! But your tip give me different checks

in order:
[ts] Cannot find name 'HtmlInputElement'.
[ts] Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'KeyBoardEvent'.